# Stanford Tagger in nltk not working due to JVM parameters

Tags: nltk, stanford-nlp, jvm-arguments

I am having a wired error while running following example code snippet

```
st = StanfordTagger('bidirectional-distsim-wsj-0-18.tagger')
st.tag('What is the airspeed of an unladen swallow ?'.split())
```

The first line worked properly but second line is giving following error.

```
Could not create the Java virtual machine.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/nltk-2.0.1rc1-   py2.6.egg/nltk/tag/stanford.py", line 51, in tag
return self.batch_tag([tokens])[0]
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/nltk-2.0.1rc1-py2.6.egg/nltk/tag/stanford.py", line 77, in batch_tag
stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/nltk-2.0.1rc1-py2.6.egg/nltk/internals.py", line 166, in java
raise OSError('Java command failed!')
OSError: Java command failed!
```

I have tried adding .usr/lib/jvm into path but still not working

Answer (score 2):

It wasn't working for me either. So I tried the following and its working perfectly.

```
st = POSTagger('path-to/stanford-postagger-full-2012-07-09/models/wsj-0-18-left3words.tagger','path-to/stanford-postagger-full-2012-07-09/stanford-postagger.jar')
```

and use nltk's tokenize method instead of Python's split()

```
taggedSentence= st.tag(nltk.word_tokenize(sentence))
```

Answer (score 2):

*I see that question is very outdated, but this days I got same error for unknown reason. It gives me a lot of headache. **But I found solution.***

First, I installed Oracle Java (here is instructions: [How To Manually Install Oracle Java on a Debian or Ubuntu VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manually-install-oracle-java-on-a-debian-or-ubuntu-vps))

Now, my python script told me more information on error. It outputs something like:

```
Forking JVM: error=12, Cannot allocate memory or error=12, Not enough space
```

Here you can read more about such problem: [Forking the JVM](http://bryanmarty.com/2012/01/14/forking-jvm/)

And to avoid that annoying error I need to edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and add the following:

```
vm.overcommit_memory = 1
```

Then restart system for the change to take effect.

Comment: Although the post is old, but I think your answer will help. Upvoting it.